# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular-cli-v6

I have an existing project using `angular 6`. I have implemented `angular universal` on my existing project.

Now when I run `build:ssr` and run `node web/server.js`. it gives me: `Node server listening on http://localhost:4000`

but when I open a browser and type `http://localhost:4000` in that browser I receive this error.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined
    at AuthInterceptor.addToken (/home/razmjo/workstation/jobsaf-website/web/server.js:362410:13)
    at AuthInterceptor.request (/home/razmjo/workstation/jobsaf-website/web/server.js:362384:21)
    at AuthInterceptor.processIntercept (/home/razmjo/workstation/jobsaf-website/web/server.js:362377:21)
    at AuthInterceptor.intercept (/home/razmjo/workstation/jobsaf-website/web/server.js:362372:21)
    . 
    .
    . 
    .
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask (/home/razmjo/workstation/jobsaf-website/web/server.js:647:21)
    at Server.ZoneTask.invoke (/home/razmjo/workstation/jobsaf-website/web/server.js:632:48)
    at Server.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:658:12)
```

Note: I have used [ngx-auth](https://github.com/serhiisol/ngx-auth) package for my authentication purpose, and this error come from that package.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the code where the .pipe is used please.

Comment: it is inside of `ngx-auth` package

Comment: @Wandrille, it is in this files. https://github.com/serhiisol/ngx-auth/blob/master/src/auth.interceptor.ts